# Remembering sharepoint password in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

I am using IE8 to open a sharepoint portal on local network. Initially, I clicked on remember password after passing domain credentials. However, now I want sharepoint to ask credentials again.

I've tried many options - Deleted all cookies, IE > Security Tab > Form Autocomplete > Deleted everything. Restarted my machine. And all I could do. Still, when I open portal, sharepoint logs me in automatically. What should I do to make IE ask for credentials again?

Answer (score 1):

This resolved it...
http://www.technize.com/how-to-delete-remembered-network-passwords-in-windows/comment-page-3/#comment-76612

Wasn't aware of something like this. pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

Check which zone your sharepoint site resides in. If its Local Intranet zone, it might be passing credentials automatically. Move the site to Internet or Trusted zone.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7/Vista:

```
Start -> Control Panel -> Credential Manager
```

But you can access this window also as **enableDeepa** wrote:

```
Start –> Run –> control userpasswords2
```

Select second tab **Advanced** -> **Manage passwords**

Answer (score 0):

Check this please:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939%28office.13%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it matters, but as a domain user you're also automatically logged in to sharepoint sites as well, so my trick was to hold shift, right click on IE, run-as different user, and run as the user i wanted to log into sharepoint as.